# datomic query over history

Tags: clojure, datomic

What is the correct way to query all the properties of a datomic db entity over its history?

For example, with the pull API or pull expressions within a query one can use wildcards to print all the properties of a given entity. However, the same approach does not work for the special history db.

```clj
(d/q '[:find [(pull ?e [*]) ...] :where [?e :test/firstName "Bob"]]  db-test)
; outputs list of Bob's properties

(d/q '[:find [(pull ?e [*]) ...] :where [?e :test/firstName "Bob"]]  (d/history db-test))
; IllegalStateException Can't pull from history
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use query to return all datoms for a single entity for all of history:

```
(d/q '[:find ?e ?a ?v ?t ?op
       :in $ ?e
       :where [?e ?a ?v ?t ?op]] 
 (d/history (d/db conn)) <Your Entity ID>)
```

Comment: Incidentally, the reason you cant use `pull` or the Entity API with a history database is that entities are point-in-time by definition: https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/entities.html#time

Comment: I had read that definition as well but was confused about how to reconcile entities being point-in-time with the fact that a query returned the same entity id for queries at different points in time. In any case, I had tried something similar to your solution, with `s/find ?e ?a ?v ?t ?op/find [?e ?a ?v ?t ?op]/g` That made all the difference, thanks!